# How to access relatively places text files in folders below a Silverlight .xap file?

Tags: c#, silverlight, isolatedstorage, code-access-security, xamlreader

In a **WPF** application, I load in xaml files with the **xamlreader** by finding the **current directory** like this:

```
public static string GetApplicationDirectory()
{
    return System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
}
```

so I can **read in a .xaml file** by getting its **absolute path** like this:

```
string pathAndFileName = GetApplicationDirectory() + @"\Layouts\LayoutMain.xaml";
```

in Silverlight the GetDirectoryName(...) method gives me a **MethodAccessException**.

**How to can I read in these .xaml resource dictionary files that are located relative to the .xap file in Silverlight?**

I can imagine I could have a directory under where my **.xap file** is placed called "Layout" with my .xaml files in it that I could read, but what would be the **Silverlight command** to read in this .txt file **relative to the URI** at which the .xap file happens to be placed?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't imagine you could as you're limited to what's in isolated storage. Unless you download those and save them in isolated storage in your app after it has started. I download .xap files after starting my SL app using WCF, as "plug-ins". Maybe that would work for you, instead?